# Where is Java path set by default?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I followed a bunch of steps to install JRE on ubuntu 13.04 -

```
sudo apt-get install update-sun-jre
```

After installation I could test it as well by writing `java -version`. However, what I was actually interested in understanding was - where is the JAVA_HOME set? I checked

1. `~./bashrc`
2. `~./profile`

there is no `export` statement added post installation. So where exactly `JAVA_HOME` is set?

Comment: did you check `~/.bash_profile` ?

Comment: I do not have any such file by default .Its a fresh machine , so chances are very less of ubuntu set up being messed up

Comment: This page may be helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally  this is what worked for me, Thank you all for coming out so quickly for help. Unfortunately I can not verify the solution as I have already got it set , and even if I delete my setting and try solution mentioned above , because in the process I have changed many environment variables I can never be sure if this is what actually solved it ..
Sorry about that

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Answer (score 0):

When you echo JAVA_HOME? Do you see a value there? If not then it is not set and the java interpreter is in the path - most probably /usr/bin (you could use the "which" or "type" command to confirm that).
On the other hand if JAVA_HOME is set then check out:
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
~/.bash_profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile

It could be in any of the above.

The reason that you are able to execute "java -version" is because it is in the path and not just JAVA_HOME being or not being set.

Answer (score 0):

Run `update-java-alternatives -l`, then `update-java-alternatives -s <version>`

On my machine,

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-6-oracle 1072 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
java-7-oracle 1077 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
java-gcj-4.6 /usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj-4.6
java-gcj-4.7 /usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj-4.7
```

So I can use,

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

**Edit**

If I needed a JAVA_HOME, I would use "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" to match the above (the value is provided by `update-java-alternatives -l`

Comment: Finally this is what worked for me http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html